# Ebay API Filter not working

Tags: android, web-services, ebay-api

I'm trying to get all the products listed by two companies by using the eBay api on my android phone. I do this by using the item filter but when I run this it will return product from all companies not from just from the companies I have stated. Why is this? Below is the http I send (MyAppIid is my actually Id and Seller1Name and Seller2Name are the companies I select)

http://open.api.ebay.com/finding?callname=findItemsAdvanced&responseencoding=JSON&appid=MyAppID&siteid=3&version=713&QueryKeywords=android&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-UK%203g&itemFilter(0).name=Seller&itemFilter(0).value(0)=Seller1Namet&itemFilter(0).value(1)=Seller2Name

Comment: Hi any can help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54333617/ebay-api-filter-records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you try to use a mix of Shopping and Finding API. It's interesting that it works at all without an API error. In any case you should use the [eBay Finding API](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/index.html) for your purpose. Here is an example how the URL may look like:

http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced&SERVICE-VERSION=1.13.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=YOUR_APP_ID_HERE&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-GB&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&callback=_cb_findItemsAdvanced&REST-PAYLOAD&itemFilter(0).name=Seller&itemFilter(0).value(0)=doria-store&itemFilter(0).value(1)=universalgadgets01&keywords=android&outputSelector(0)=SellerInfo

I've created an example in our [Live API Playground](https://sdk.intradesys.com/s/4c56ff4ce4aaf9573aa5dff913df997a). You can adapt the call to your needs and execute it to see the response directly in the response area. When you're done, click on "Retrieve JS code" and you will get ready-to-use JS code including the URL for the call with all its parameters you've configured.

Comment: Thanks, this is handy. I did notice retrieving JS code the affiliate array continues with the itemFilter array count